# Issue with POST Request being passed as GET

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm going to insert the whole module in case you need to see other aspects of the code. The call in question is the addTracks method. The project is to allow the person to search the spotify library, create a playlist of songs, then add the playlist to their account. Everything works fine, besides the tracks actually saving to the account, I get a 401 error on the API, but both Chrome and FireFox also label it as a GET call, instead of as a POST. The error is an authentication error, but I should be authorized correctly, the only odd thing for authorization is the scope, which is taken care of in the redirect in getAccessToken(). What am I missing here? In case you need it: [Spotify add track documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/add-tracks-to-playlist/)

```js
let accessToken;
let expiresIn;
const clientId = '86f8f621d81a4ce18bd21da9fd2da2b1';
const redirectURI = 'http://localhost:3000/';

const Spotify = {
  getAccessToken() {
    if (accessToken) {
      return accessToken;
    } else if (window.location.href.match(/access_token=([^&]*)/) != null) {
      accessToken = window.location.href.match(/access_token=([^&]*)/)[1];
      expiresIn = window.location.href.match(/expires_in=([^&]*)/)[1];
      window.setTimeout(() => accessToken = '', expiresIn * 1000);
      window.history.pushState('Access Token', null, '/');
    } else {
      window.location = `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=${clientId}&response_type=token&scope=playlist-modify-public&redirect_uri=${redirectURI}`;
    }
  },

  async search(term) {
    if (accessToken === undefined) {
      this.getAccessToken();
    }
    try {
      let response = await fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?type=track&q=${term}`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
        }
      });
      if (response.ok) {
        let jsonResponse = await response.json();
        let tracks = jsonResponse.tracks.items.map(track => ({
          id: track.id,
          name: track.name,
          artist: track.artists[0].name,
          album: track.album.name,
          uri: track.uri
        }));
        return tracks;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  },

  async savePlaylist(name, trackURIs) {
    if (accessToken === undefined) {
      this.getAccessToken();
    }
    if (name === undefined || trackURIs === undefined) {
      return;
    } else {
      let userId = await this.findUserId();
      let playlistID;
      fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/${userId}/playlists`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
          "Content-Type": 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          name: name
        })
      }).then(response => {
        return response.json()
      }).then(playlist => {
        playlistID = playlist.id;
        this.addTracks(playlistID, trackURIs, userId);
      });
    }
  },

  addTracks(playlistID, trackURIs, userId) {
    console.log(trackURIs);
    fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/${userId}/playlists/${playlistID}/tracks`), {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        "Content-Type": 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        uris: trackURIs
      })
    }
  },

  findUserId() {
    if (accessToken === undefined) {
      this.getAccessToken();
    }
    let userId;
    return fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/me`, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
      }
    }).then(response => {
      return response.json()
    }).then(jsonResponse => {
      userId = jsonResponse.id;
      return userId;
    });
  }
};

export default Spotify;
```

Comment: You'll want to show how you're calling `addTracks`, as that can make a difference.

Comment: In the addTracks method you have a ')' after the url in the fetch method call, so it no longer passes the second argument where you specify it's a POST and the authentication data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm beginner but probably you should check bracket in fetch() method in addTracks()

```
addTracks(playlistID, trackURIs, userId) {
    console.log(trackURIs);
    fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/${userId}/playlists/${playlistID}/tracks`->)<-, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        "Content-Type": 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        uris: trackURIs
      })
    }
  },
```

correct

```
addTracks(playlistID, trackURIs, userId) {
        console.log(trackURIs);
        fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/${userId}/playlists/${playlistID}/tracks`, {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
            "Content-Type": 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            uris: trackURIs
          })
        })
      },
```